# Set of values of an operation on permutations of a set

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have been trying to solve the following problem:

Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,...,2017\}$. Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of set $A$. Define $B = \{|\sigma(i) - i|, 1\leq i \leq 2017\}.$ Show that the cardinal of $B$ is $\leq$ 2016. (In other words,there is no permutation $\sigma$ such that $B$ contains every value from $0$ to $2016$).

Here are some of the things i've tried:

1) Show that the sum of elements of B is always $<0+1+\dots+2016$. This is false.

2) Work modulo 2 (because $|\sigma(i) - i| \equiv \sigma(i) - i \text{ }(\text{mod 2})$). This gives only a partial result. Consider the same question, but replace 2017 with an arbitrary number $n$. If the cardinal of B is maximal, we obtain $B=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$, so 
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |\sigma(i)-i|\equiv \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (\sigma(i)-i)\equiv 0\equiv \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} i\equiv \dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\pmod 2,$$
which is not possible if $n \equiv 2,3 $ (mod 4). But $2017 \equiv 1$ (mod 4).

How could one go about solving this?

Comment: Will this work: 1 must map to 2017 because this is the only way to have the difference 2016. Now the difference 2015 can be achieved only if 2017 maps to 2. Now the difference 2014 can only be achieved if 2 maps to 2016 etc. - you go zig-zagging and eventually you won't be able to complete the cycle as the last element would need to map to itself (so nothing will map to 1).

Comment: @user8734617 This is not the only case. It is possible to have, for example, $2016\mapsto1\mapsto2017\mapsto3$ or $2015\mapsto1\mapsto2017\mapsto2$ or a whole lot of other possibilities.

Comment: You are right. Will keep thinking about it. I feel there will eventually be some zig-zagging of this kind, but will refrain from posting until I know the answer (or someone else answers). Thanks.